# SQL Server Column to Row and Join Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I join two tables, with one table has multiple row(2 rows)?

For example:

Table1 Name has two rows, apple and banana

```
Name
Apple
Banana
```

Table 2 has three columns, with only one row

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
a        b        c
```

What I expect the result be like:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC Name1 Name2
a       b       c       Apple Banana
```

Please help, thanks you

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a platform for code requests, please provide your code you have worked on and we might help

Comment: Research "pivot"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from table2 t2 cross join
     (select min(name) as name1, max(name) as name2
      from table1
     ) t1;
```